# Styling script for jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

It's pretty dummy question. please have look at code

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

can anyone tell the the name of the script library or whatever what I can get line no, print button, PDF button or view plain or copy to clipboard like in the code.

Comment: i think he meant how to post code snippets in a page

Comment: @robobooga so what is the technical term?

Comment: i've given my answer below to where i found the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

**EDIT**

link to configuration to print, copy, etc  : http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/configuration/strings.html